# How to use multiple if in lamda function?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, datetime, lambda

In the date frame I have Date column and now want to extract a new column from Date called 'status' if Date> CurrentDate (datetime.now()) update the status as Expired, if Date< CurrentDate update the status as SW Expires and year in the Date with the quarter (SW Expires 2018-Q4), if Date == CurrentDate or "X" or "Y": update the status as Current else NA.
Say:CurrentDate=19-06-2019

```
Date              Status
2019-06-28      SW Expires 2018-Q2
2020-01-20      SW Expires 2018-Q1
2018-07-18      SW Expired
X               Current
Y               Current
2019-06-20      Current


df['Qtr'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.quarter
df['Qtr']=pd.PeriodIndex(pd.to_datetime(df['Date']), freq='Q')
df['Qtr']=df['Qtr'].astype(str)
df['Qtr']="SW Expires"+' '+df['Qtr']


df['Status'] = df['Date'].apply (lambda x : 'SW Expired' if x > 
CurrentDate else(Midrange_SWProduct['Qtr'] x < CurrentDate else('current' 
Midrange_SWProduct['Qtr'] x == CurrentDate or 'X' or 'Y' else NA )))
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way is two write custom function and call in apply function.

```
def custom_funct(row):
     do anthing
df['res']=df.apply(lambda row: custom_funct(row),axis=1)
```